# Wordpress page template option not displaying in dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using wordpress 4.9.6 version it's not showing *page template* option. I reinstalled wordpress and using default themes and plugins. I don't know the exact reason for this. Please help me out of this. Tell me the reason why it occurs.

[image]

Comment: Do your page templates have Template Name: TEMPLATE NAME (ie; Template Name: My Page) at the top of the file in a comment?

Answer (score 1):

The solution in my case was to add `index.php` file in theme's root folder.

It appears that adding my theme into **Git** repository (with Git Desktop) and selecting default `.gitignore` file of Wordpress incorrectly ignores the `index.php` file inside theme's root folder, so the file was never uploaded to the server after deploy and WordPress does not recognize the theme as valid one - hence the missing drop-down with template selection.

Answer (score 0):

Your theme must have [template file](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/). The default WordPress themes does not have that by default.

You need to create a new `.php` file, name it whatever and add this following code in the top:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: your template name
 *
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way to create a Template, is as follows:

**Creating the Template file:**

1. Open up your preferred Text Editor.  I would recommend [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for its 'best of both worlds' feel.  It offers a greater range of tools than 'Notepad' whilst not being too overwhelming.
2. Next, you will need to enter the following code:

   ```
   <?php
   // Template Name: Name of Template.
   ?>
   ```
3. Then head to `File > Save as ...` and enter your desired file name.  Then within the 'Save as type' dropdown menu, select 'PHP Hypertext Preprocessor file'.  This file type will be appended with a series of file extensions, within a set of brackets.
4. Go ahead and select 'Save'.
5. Of course, don't forget to enter your relevant Template coding and save as you go along.

**Upload to website:**

With your Template file completed, you will now be ready to upload this to your website.  One of the easiest way to do this, is as follows:

1. Download [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/).  If you are unsure of which version to download, stick with 'Download FileZilla Client'.
2. Once downloaded and installed, open the program.  Then login, with your site's credentials.  If you are unsure of these, you will need to seek assistance from your hosting provider.
3. By now, you should see a screen like:

[image: FileZilla Dashboard]

4. The above image has a lot of blank spaces.  If you are logged in, these blank spaces will be populated with various folder and file names etc.  Referring to the above image, take take of the contents within the red box.  This text bar may be populated.  Just enter '/httpdocs/wp-content/themes'.  Alternatively, you can scroll through the Folders manually.
5. All you then need to do, is identify the relevant Theme and drag over the desired template file and drop it into the relevant theme's folder.
6. When it comes to WordPress themes, you may first want to familiarise yourself with [Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).  Simply put, if you are not the Theme Author, you will need to create a Child Theme.  If you modify the Parent theme, any file modifications will be lost.  Whilst this wouldn't be the case, in this instance, you may wish to take this opportunity in understanding Child Themes and implementing said themes now, in preparation for future modifications.

Comment: This is so stupid! The dropdown is missing completely in his case. This don't helped me too.

Comment: If your Theme does not specify a Template File, the Drop Down option will not appear.  As such, follow my answer and the drop down menu should then appear.